# largestChangeId being returned inconsistent?

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm using the drive change feed to find changes of files in Google Drive.  I have been experiencing some inconsistency.  I just tested using the API Explorer found here :

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/changes/list

On one user the largestChangeId returned was 1208, although when setting the startChangeId to 1208, the request returned 6 entries, including the change of 1208, and each other change being higher than 1208.  I also have the flags includeDeleted = true, includeSubscribed = false.

I then tried on another user, the returned ID was 136023.  When using this value with the same params as above Drive returned 0 entries, which I expected.

Then I tried on a third user, the returned ID was 8267.  Then setting the call again with the same params as above Drive returned 1 entries, which had the same change id of 8267.

Note all three accounts are testing accounts on a test domain in which no documents are being modified or shared.

So three users three results making the same call.  Is this expected or a better question, what should I expect when making this call. In the documentation it states : " Change ID to start listing changes from. (string)".  When it says from and you are returned the highest ID I would expect 0 results to be returned.

Thanks.